# EJB relationship

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'm writing a web application of management of the computer consumables to develop in JEE.  In my database the personal table is linked to the login table; I make an insertion of a staff with his login, and then just after insertion, I execute the following code:

```
Personnel personnel = personnelFacade.find(id);
    List<Page> pages = pageFacade.findByNiveau(personnel.getLoginList().get(0).getNiveauAcces());
```

I get this error:

```
Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[SettingPersonnal]: Servlet.service() for servlet SettingPersonnal threw exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.get(IndirectList.java:442)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The login list is empty, you need to debug your code and invistigate about the cause

Answer (score 0):

Your LoginList is empty. The error is thrown when you try to `get(0)` from the LoginList. If you do not want to be able to insert a record with no values in the loginlist you can use Bean Validation like this:

```
@NotNull @Size(min = 1)
List<MyLoginClass> loginList;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer what is curious is that when I redefine the server glassfish and I execute the code `Personnel personnel = personnelFacade.find(id);
    List<Page> pages = pageFacade.findByNiveau(personnel.getLoginList().get(0).getNiveauAcces());` on the same staff that I came to record  its walk without problem

Comment: What do you mean with redefining the server? When does it happen? Only after an insert?